# Printing out an object with custom toString()

Tags: java, object, printing

I created my own object that takes in three variables from a text file. A date, opening number, and closing number. I'm using my own object and need to create my own toString method that prints out "date,opening,closing".

These are the constructors.

```
 public stock(String dt, double opening, double closing)
        throws ParseException {

    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy").parse(dt);
    GregorianCalendar gregCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    greCal.setTime(date);

    this.open = open;
    this.close = close;
    this.date = greCal;
}

public String date() {
    String date;
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    date = dateformat.format(this.date.getTime());
    return date;

}

public double opening(){
    open = this.open;

    return open;
}

public double closing(){
    close = this.close;


    return close;
```

And this is the toString I had.

```
public String toString(){

    String close1 = ""+ close;
    String open1 = ""+ open;
    String date1 = "" + date;


    return(date1+open1+close1);
```

The issue is when I try to print the object it seems to print out the contents of a Gregorian calender which is what I'm using for date. Once I read the contents of the file, I added them to the object and tried to print them but that's were the problem was.

```
  stock newStock = new stock(temp, opening, closing);
```

Then it gets added to a linked list and I try to print.

Comment: Instead of telling a story, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, provide an input, output and expected output.

Comment: In your constructor, you are setting the class variables to the same value, instead of `this.open = open;` it should be `this.open = opening;` the same goes for `close`

Comment: Ah sorry for this wall of text, but I just figured out its not printing the date I inputed, but the current date of the computer in Gregorian calendar form.  And ya open and close were printing zero but that was fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of apologizing, post an MCVE.

Comment: what is input `dt` value you are passing?

Comment: Yeah, it is better that you post an MCVE as suggested by user1803551 so that we can better help you -:)